# Pythonic Approach: Finding First Matching Path With Minimal Runtime

Tags: python

What is an efficient way to find the first matching path with a fairly low runtime in Python?

For example,

I am given a path as input:

```
test1/testA/testB
```

and a set of paths that can be matched to (in my use case, this would be in the thousands).

```
test1/testB
test1/testA
testC/testD
```

There will not be any overlapping paths like below and can only be matched to one path:

```
test1/testA
test1/testA/testB
```

In the example above, since `test1/testA/testB` is in `test1/testA`, I want to return `test1/testA`.

My approach would be to build an in-memory tree and mark each node in the tree if it is an endpoint. Then, I would traverse the tree each time to find if a path can be matched. Unfortunately, this would require a fair bit of work.

Is there a Python function or library to accomplish this fairly easily? Or would I need to write this from scratch?

Comment: Can you explain  the problem you are trying to solve? There might be a better approach than what you are attempting.

Comment: When you say "there are no overlapping paths" do you mean that all the termini will be unique?

Comment: I'm trying to solve an issue where I have a file path, and I need the project it came from. I have a list of project names and their associated paths. However, the file path may not necessarily be a direct match to the project path but may reside inside the project path. I would be calling this function potentially multiple times per second and there could be thousands of project paths.

Comment: All termini will be unique in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly address the issue of "how to structure the algorithm" (looks like more clarification is needed from the comments above) but...

If these are actual real-world file/directory paths, then you may want to use the [`os.path.commonprefix` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.commonprefix) in the standard library. It can match, well, common prefixes of paths in a OS/platform-agnostic way.

You should also normalize all the paths as either absolute paths (with `os.path.abspath`) or relative paths (with `os.path.relative`) before starting.

Answer (score 1):

If the input path is not overly long, in terms of slash-separated
components; and if the set of possible matches are all full components;
i.e., something like `stA/tes` would not appear; then I would do this.

```
Read the set of possible matches into a `set`.
Divide the input path into all possible substrings; in this case:
test1
test1/testA
test1/testA/testB
testA
testA/testB
testB

For `n` components there will be `n(n+1)/2` substrings.

Search the `set` for each one: if substring in matches: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For the problem as given you can cut the search space down pretty far by indexing your list of paths with the head and tail of the path:

```
paths =[
    'a/b/c/d',
    'a/b/d',
    'a/c/b/s/e',
    'a/e',
    'a/b/d/e'
]

def head_and_tail(pth, offset = -1):
  splitted = pth.split('/')
  return splitted[0], splitted[offset]

index = dict ([(head_and_tail(p),[]) for p in paths])
# produce a dictionary with each head/tail combination as a key and a list as value

for p in paths:
  ht = head_and_tail(p)
  index[ht].append(p)

# now index contains all paths indexed by their head and tail

def search (pth):
  ht = head_and_tail(pth, -2)
  root = "/".join(pth.split("/"))[:-1][:-1]
  for item in index[ht]:
      if item == root:
        return item
  return None

print search ("a/b/c/d/e")
```

This will work well for 'broad' data with lots of paths coming from unique roots or ending in unique leaves.  It won't offer much speedup where the data is 'deep' with few roots.